# Inserting multiple entries into Mysql Database Using Propel ORM

Tags: php, mysql, propel

I am writing a web application using PHP. For the first time I started using Propel ORM. I am reading values from array and sending them to a function which has Propel Insert Queries. The function is like this.

```
public function someFunction
{
    $nid=10;
    $sample_array = array("first","second");
        foreach($sample_array as $items){
            $this->saveTags($items,$nid);
        } 
}

public function saveTags($tags,$nid)
{
   error_log("SetTag: ".$this->tags->setTag($tags));
   error_log("SetNid: ".$this->tags->setNid($nid));
   error_log("Save: ".$this->tags->save());
}
```

When I execute the program, the first item "first" saves but immediately overwritten by second item i.e "second". Below are the apache error logs.

```
 SetTag: Tid: null\nNid: null\nTag: first\n
 SetNid: Tid: null\nNid: 30\nTag: first\n
 Save: 1
 SetTag: Tid: 11\nNid: 30\nTag: second\n
 SetNid: Tid: 11\nNid: 30\nTag: second\n
 Save: 1
```

As you can see the first item is replaced by second item!
Any solution to prevent this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is `$this->tags` ?

I guess, since your are using `$this->`, that you use the object every time you are going inside the function `saveTags()`.

What you can do is to create a new tags every time, something like:

```
public function saveTags($tags,$nid)
{
   $tags = new Tags();
   $tags->setTag($tags);
   $tags->setNid($nid);
   $tags->save();

   return $tags;
}
```

This way, every time you will call `saveTags` it will create a **new** tag.